# Scala: Dynamically access companion objects from child classes

Tags: scala

I want a couple of classes with companion objects in order to access shared values from a class instance as well as from the companion object, when I don't have an instance.

Ultimately I want to parse a string and create instances of matching classes and also the other way round, create a string from an instance.

The following code works, but it seems overly complicated:

```
abstract class Person(val age: Int = 0) {
    val pronoun: String
    override def toString = pronoun + " is " + age + " years old"
}

class Man(override val age: Int) extends Person {
    val pronoun = Man.pronoun
}

class Woman(override val age: Int) extends Person {
    val pronoun = Woman.pronoun
}

object Man extends Person {
    val pronoun = "he"
}

object Woman extends Person {
    val pronoun = "she"
}

object Person {
    def fromString(pronoun: String, age: Int): Option[Person] = {
        pronoun match {
            case Man.pronoun => Some(new Man(age))
            case Woman.pronoun => Some(new Woman(age))
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}

// Man.pronoun
// -> should return "he"

// Woman.pronoun
// -> should return "she"

// new Man(30).toString
// -> should return "he is 30 years old"

// Person.fromString("she", 20)
// -> should return a Some(Woman) with age = 20
```

So, for this to work I create a class and a companion object for each child class and manually reference the `pronoun` from the companion object (e.g. `val pronoun = Man.pronoun`).

Side note: Setting the default value `age = 0` in the abstract class makes things further down a bit easier, but it doesn't seem right?!

I've tried using traits etc. but all with no success. Is there a better way of achieving this with less repetitive code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the problem, I would simplify it by doing:

```
case class Person(pronoun: String, age: Int) {
  override def toString = s"$pronoun is $age years old"
}
```

And that should solve it, but I guess the problem you presented is a simplification of a more complex one, so my solution became:

```
trait Person {
  protected def age: Int
  protected def pronoun: String
  override def toString = s"$pronoun is $age years old"
}

case class Man(override val age: Int) extends Person {
  override protected def pronoun: String = Person.SHE
}
case class Woman(override val age: Int) extends Person {
  override protected def pronoun: String = Person.HE
}

object Person {

  val HE = "he"
  val SHE = "she"

  def parse(pronoun: String, age: Int): Option[Person] = {
    pronoun match {
      case HE => Some(Man(age))
      case SHE => Some(Woman(age))
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"pronoun $pronoun was not recognized")
    }
  }

}
```

This doesn't look awful to me, solves the problem and is very readable. 
Having said that, your code doesn't look wrong (the 0 default does). It seems complex but it took 2 seconds for me to understand what you were doing, and readability is very important these days.

Hope this will help you. Regards!

Comment: That's right, my example above is a simplification. I guess my problem was, that I wasn't thinking of putting the "pronouns" in the object. Secondly I was unaware that I could indeed use a trait here and instead of an abstract class. Although very similar to the second answer, I'll select this one as correct, because I find the trait solution slightly cleaner here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What are the constraints that you must follow? E.g. do you have to be able to invoke `Man.pronoun`? Because one option is to simply create `ManPronoun` and `WomanPronoun` fields in the `Person` object and remove the `Man` and `Woman` companion objects. Also, what's the point of 0 default age value? You can simply pass the age to `Person`.

```
abstract class Person(val age: Int) {
  val pronoun: String
  override def toString = pronoun + " is " + age + " years old"
}

class Man(override val age: Int) extends Person(age) {
  val pronoun = Person.ManPronoun 
}

class Woman(override val age: Int) extends Person(age) {
  val pronoun = Person.WomanPronoun
}  

object Person {

  val ManPronoun = "he"
  val WomanPronoun = "she"

  def fromString(pronoun: String, age: Int): Option[Person] = {
    pronoun match {
      case ManPronoun   => Some(new Man(age))
      case WomanPronoun => Some(new Woman(age))
      case _            => None
    }
  }
}
```

If you must have the pronoun field inside `Man` and `Woman` objects, well, then you have to have `Man` and `Woman` objects. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, too! I set the default value 0, because I had companion objects for each class that extended `Person` which required an `age` argument. The only reason I didn't select this as the "correct" answer was because with the trait solution I don't have to carry around the `age` argument. It might become handy with other requirements, so thanks for your answer as well.

Comment: Hah, no problem, I don't care about being elected "correct" but about helping. I left it as an abstract class just because you had it that way :) I prefer traits too. If you don't have a special reason to use an abstract class, gravitate towards traits. They are a lot of fun when you start stacking them around etc.